# How can I improve the performance of an animation which changes images of unknown size in a grid?

Tags: performance, css, animation, css-animations

I built a grid of images (stored in `$image`), which may change in a random order with a random delay. The performance was okay, as long as I haven't had `background-position: center` and `background-size: cover` in it. Now with these attributes the images flickers while blending in. How may I improve the rendering performance?

My scss looks like this

```
@mixin image-tiles() {
  // First image
  @for $i from 1 through $total-image-count {
    $firstImg: nth($images, $i);

    &.img-#{$i} {
      // set the default image if animations are not defined
      background-image: url('../../' + $firstImg);
    }

    // Second image
    @for $j from 1 through $total-image-count {
      // Third image
      @for $k from 1 through $total-image-count {
        &.img-#{$i}-#{$j}-#{$k}{
          animation-name: random-image-transition-#{$i}-#{$j}-#{$k};
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @for $d from 0 through ($image-shown-duration * 2) - 1 {
    &.delayed-by-#{$d} {
      animation-delay: 0.5s * $d;
    }
  }

  &.img {
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-duration: $image-shown-duration * 3s, $image-shown-duration * 3s; // three stages
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through $total-image-count {
  $firstImg: nth($images, $i);
  @for $j from 1 through $total-image-count {
    $secondImg: nth($images, $j);
    @for $k from 1 through $total-image-count {
      $thirdImg: nth($images, $k);

      @keyframes random-image-transition-#{$i}-#{$j}-#{$k} {
        from {
          background-image: url('../../' + $firstImg);
        }

        16% {
          background-image: url('../../' + $firstImg);
        }

        23% {
          background-image: url('../../' + $secondImg);
        }

        50% {
          background-image: url('../../' + $secondImg);
        }

        56% {
          background-image: url('../../' + $thirdImg);
        }

        89% {
          background-image: url('../../' + $thirdImg);
        }

        to {
          background-image: url('../../' + $firstImg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.tile-teaser-content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80vw;
  padding-bottom: 45%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.tile-teaser-content {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 80vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;

  .tile {
    @include image-tiles();

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
    height: 100% / $tile-per-col-count;
    width: 100% / $tile-per-row-count;
  }
}
```

the html would be

```
<div class="tile-teaser-content-wrapper">
    <div class="tile-teaser-content">
        <div class="tile img img-1 img-1-2-3 delayed-by-0"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-4 img-4-5-6 delayed-by-1"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-7 img-7-8-9 delayed-by-2"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-1 img-1-2-3 delayed-by-3"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-4 img-4-5-6 delayed-by-4"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-7 img-7-8-9 delayed-by-5"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-1 img-1-2-3 delayed-by-1"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-4 img-4-5-6 delayed-by-2"></div>
        <div class="tile img img-7 img-7-8-9 delayed-by-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a performance problem, it is mode deep than that.

the background-image size is a property of the element. When you are making a transition on this, and the 2 images have different sizes, the browser is unable to set **both** dimensions at the same time, and so you have a wrong result.

The usual way to solve this is to have 2 elements, each with a background-image, and play with the opacity of one of them.

By the way, animating a background image has still poor browser support, so this is another reason to change your approach